# pgAdmin III - Does it show list of enum values when I fill table?

Tags: database, postgresql, enums, postgis, pgadmin

I create a new enum type in pgAdmin III. I post the code used:

```
CREATE TYPE "PRova_3".e_dispositivo AS ENUM
   ('call',
    'e-mail',
    'sms');
ALTER TYPE "PRova_3".e_dispositivo
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

After that, I create a column (device) with this data type.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/tuc0nkfigz3b7ar/2x.JPG?dl=0

However, when I insert a value in that field I don't see the list of options to choose. I can only insert the value, if it is valid I can continue, otherwise an error window appear.

I would like that the end-users can see among possible values to choose.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/r0va9uimzxovsre/2x_w.JPG?dl=0

Can I set this showing list in some way?

Answer (score 1):

Actually not possible - sadly. But you can show your custom types inside the browser. Go to file --> options --> browser and activate types. Now you can easily see the labels for your types, With this you can also create custom types with an UI BUT this doesn't improve the usability while filling the DB with pgAdmin III.